# How can i check if specific value exist in list with yq

Tags: linux, bash, yq

How can i check if specific value exist in list with yq . This is my yaml

```
projects:
   p1:
     - "sample/project/app1"
     - "sample/project/app2"
```

This is my test code  but it return false

```
cat test.yaml | yq '.projects.p1 | has("sample/project/app1")'
false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please specify [which implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) of `yq` you are using.

With [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), you could use `any_c`:

```bash
yq '.projects.p1 | any_c(. == "sample/project/app1")' test.yaml
```

With [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq), you could use `IN`:

```bash
yq 'IN(.projects.p1[]; "sample/project/app1")' test.yaml
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot check whether array contains a string with `has()`. Please try instead:

```
yq < test.yaml '.projects.p1 | index("sample/project/app1") != null'
true
```

Comment: Great you know `yq` also :) how could I learn more on `jq` and `yq` I know very basics on these. Your Kind guidance is appreciated cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 thank you for the comment. I have very limited experience in `jq`. My main source of information is Google :).
As you know, `yq` is just a wrapper for `jq`, and the filter syntax is the same. We don't need to learn `yq` specific syntax. Cheers.